# Multiple input types sum

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to sum multiple inputs together from select, radio and text.

I have the following code, which works, but cancels out each different input, i'm looking to add them all together.

I know there would be a better way to structure this, but I can't seem to work out a good solution.

**View**

```
    <select>
    <option value='0.0'>Product 1</option>
    <option value='0.5'>Product 2</option>
    <option value='1.0'>Product 3</option>
    <option value='0.5'>Product 4</option>
    </select>

    <h4>Desired price</h4>
    <input class="inputBox form-control" type="text" id="desired_price" >

    <form>
    <label class="radio inline">
    <input type="radio" name="location" value="0.1" > location 1
    </label>
    <label class="radio inline">
    <input type="radio" name="location" value="0.1" > location 2
    </label>
    <label class="radio inline">
    <input type="radio" name="location" value="0.4" > location 3
    </label>
    <label class="radio inline">
    <input type="radio" name="location" value="0.7" > location 4
    </label>
    <label class="radio inline">
    <input type="radio" name="location" value="1.0" > location 5
    </label>
    </form>

<b id="score_total">0</b>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var desiredPrice = document.getElementById("desired_price");

 desiredPrice.onkeyup = calc;

 function calc() {
  document.getElementById("score_total").innerHTML = parseFloat(desiredPrice.value).toFixed(1);
    }

 // All radios sum gathered
 $('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
 var total = 0;
 $('input[type=radio]:checked').each(function(){
  total += Number($(this).val());
 });
  $('#score_total').html(total);
 });

 // select
 $('select').change(function(){
  var variety = 0;
 $('select :selected').each(function() {
  variety += Number($(this).val());
 });
  $('#score_total').html(variety);
 });

});
```

Comment: Seems you have not closed your input tags

Comment: Basically, you have to check current values for all inputs, on every change/event: so, on keypress, when user is on text field, first check values of radios and select, when radio is clicked, check text field value and select value, and so on... and change total accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must define a 'change' event handler for #score_total, and then trigger #score_total change event on select, radio, and textbox change.

this code can help you.

you can edit code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/a3dmorteza/hsuxs3uL/) and use it after edit.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#score_total').on('change', function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('select, [type=text], [type=radio]:checked').each(function(){
      sum += Number($(this).val()); 
    });
    $(this).text(sum);
  });
  $('select').on('change', function(){
   $('#score_total').trigger('change'); 
  });
  $('[type=text]').on('keyup', function(){
   $('#score_total').trigger('change');
  });
  $('[type=radio]').on('click', function(){
   $('#score_total').trigger('change');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value='0.0'>Product 1</option>
  <option value='0.5'>Product 2</option>
  <option value='1.0'>Product 3</option>
  <option value='0.5'>Product 4</option>
</select>

<h4>Desired price</h4>
<input class="inputBox form-control" type="text" id="desired_price">

<form>
  <label class="radio inline">
    <input type="radio" name="location" value="0.1"> location 1
  </label>
  <label class="radio inline">
    <input type="radio" name="location" value="0.1"> location 2
  </label>
  <label class="radio inline">
    <input type="radio" name="location" value="0.4"> location 3
  </label>
  <label class="radio inline">
    <input type="radio" name="location" value="0.7"> location 4
  </label>
  <label class="radio inline">
    <input type="radio" name="location" value="1.0"> location 5
  </label>
</form>

<b id="score_total">0</b>
```

Comment: This is a perfect and elegant approach. Cheers.

Comment: this is just for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var totalValues = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]; // array that stores parcial totals
   var desiredPrice = document.getElementById("desired_price");

     var totalCalc = function(){ //Calculates and displays total sum
       document.getElementById("score_total").innerHTML = (totalValues[0] + totalValues[1] + totalValues[2]).toFixed(1);
   }

   //Functions to calculate each block sum
   var calcDesiredPrice = function(){     
     totalValues[0] = parseFloat(desiredPrice.value);
     totalCalc();
   }

   var calcRadios = function(){
     var total = 0;
     $('input[type=radio]:checked').each(function(){
       total += Number($(this).val());
     });
     totalValues[1] = total;
     totalCalc();
   }

   var calcSelect = function(){
     var variety = 0;
     $('select :selected').each(function() {
      variety += Number($(this).val());
     });

     totalValues[2] = variety;
     totalCalc();
   } 

   //Set the handlers for the form changes
   desiredPrice.onkeyup = calcDesiredPrice;
   $('input[type=radio]').change(calcRadios);
   $('select').change(calcSelect); 

});
```